# Slickgrid checkbox event issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, slickgrid

I'm using Slikgrid javascript library and I'm following this tutorial to make a grid with checkboxes : [exemple4](http://mleibman.github.io/SlickGrid/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html)

the code used is below :

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../slick.grid.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="examples.css" type="text/css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../controls/slick.columnpicker.css" type="text/css"/>
<style>
.slick-cell-checkboxsel {
background: #f0f0f0;
border-right-color: silver;
border-right-style: solid;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position:relative">
<div style="width:600px;">
<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%;height:500px;"></div>
</div>
<div class="options-panel">
<h2>Demonstrates:</h2>
<ul>
<li>Checkbox row select column</li>
</ul>
<h2>View Source:</h2>
<ul>
<li><A href="https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/blob/gh-pages/examples/example-checkbox-row-select.html" target="_sourcewindow"> View the source for this example on Github</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
</div>
<script src="../lib/firebugx.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery-1.7.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="../lib/jquery.event.drag-2.2.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.core.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.checkboxselectcolumn.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.autotooltips.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellrangedecorator.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellrangeselector.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellcopymanager.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.cellselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="../plugins/slick.rowselectionmodel.js"></script>
<script src="../controls/slick.columnpicker.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.formatters.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.editors.js"></script>
<script src="../slick.grid.js"></script>
<script>
var grid;
var data = [];
var options = {
editable: true,
enableCellNavigation: true,
asyncEditorLoading: false,
autoEdit: false
};
var columns = [];
$(function () {
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
var d = (data[i] = {});
d[0] = "Row " + i;
}
var checkboxSelector = new Slick.CheckboxSelectColumn({
cssClass: "slick-cell-checkboxsel"
});
columns.push(checkboxSelector.getColumnDefinition());
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
columns.push({
id: i,
name: String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0) + i),
field: i,
width: 100,
editor: Slick.Editors.Text
});
}
grid = new Slick.Grid("#myGrid", data, columns, options);
grid.setSelectionModel(new Slick.RowSelectionModel({selectActiveRow: false}));
grid.registerPlugin(checkboxSelector);
var columnpicker = new Slick.Controls.ColumnPicker(columns, grid, options);
})
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm trying to respond to a checkbox click event but I found no way to handle that.
What I would like to do is to create an array that holds the first row elements data like ["Row 0",...] and display it when the first checkbox is checked. How can I handle that event?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The event on which you want to take action is [onSelectedRowsChanged](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Grid-Events). The only problem is that there is no direct link back to the specific row that triggered the event, as is available when using [getCellFromEvent](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki/Slick.Grid#getCellFromEvent) when listening to other events, such as `onMouseEnter`.

If you combine the two approaches, you can use `onMouseEnter` to "track" the current row.

```
var context = {};
grid.onMouseEnter.subscribe(function (evt, args) {
    var cell = grid.getCellFromEvent(evt)
    context.rowIndex = cell.row;
    context.row = grid.getDataItem(cell.row);
})
```

Handle the data manipulation / rendering within `onSelectedRowsChanged`.

```
grid.onSelectedRowsChanged.subscribe(function (evt, args) {

    if (!context.row) {
        var rows = grid.getData();
        for (r in rows) {
            var row = rows[r]
            for (i = 1; i < columns.length; ++i) {
                row[i] = args.rows.length == 0 ? '' : dataContainer[r][i]
            }
        }
        grid.invalidateAllRows();
    } else {

        var display = args.rows.indexOf(context.rowIndex) >= 0;

        for (i = 1; i < columns.length; ++i) {
            context.row[i] = display ? dataContainer[context.rowIndex][i] : ''
        }

        grid.invalidateRow(context.rowIndex);
    }

    grid.render();
})
```

In this context, `dataContainer` is a "map" vs an array. Depending on the size of your data, you would want a faster lookup.

**Note** This implementation only works if using the `RowSelectionModel` option of `{selectActiveRow:false}`. Otherwise, a more custom data handling implementation is required.

## [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/origineil/tbngfLmo/)

Comment: How to manage sorting and searching functionality with this example?